# While installing Arc theme I mistyped the word "deb" to "dep" and now I'm getting errors

Tags: apt, 15.10, themes

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.10/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arc-theme
```

After this I am getting this error in Synaptic:

```
E: Type 'dep' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Go to the repository dialog to correct the problem.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

I can't even carry out any updates.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the terminal and type:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list
```

This will open up the file in gedit.
Find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) the line with the `dep` entry and delete it.
Save file and close gedit. Then try updating again.

Comment: @masterpiece Kindly accept the answer and  give me an upvote :)